# Deeply regret email resignation

Tags: professionalism

I recently sent a resignation email to my boss because I was anxious about our 2 weeks notice policy. Her presence at the office varies as we're both college students. I feel awful and want to make amends. She was graceful and sent back nice comments and her willingness to provide recommendations if I ever need one.

I want to apologize to her in person but I've been so high on anxiety that I didn't take the two chances to speak with her when I saw her later in person. I realize now that I could have asked to schedule a meeting instead in email instead of informing her in that way, but I can't take it back no matter how much I want to. She knew I was leaving the program eventually because we spoke about it in person before but I regret that I officially confirmed it this way.

I do have a few more days of work to have the chance to speak with her. I am afraid my apology would worsen the situation, but it is troubling me a good deal. If I do meet with her, I might have to again email and this time ask for a few minutes for a private meeting. I feel like I don't deserve to request this after my actions. I still feel very foolish. Would requesting to speak with her in person worsen everything?

Comment: Why do you think it wrong to tender your resignation in an email?

Comment: Has your manager expressed any displeasure?

Comment: I am worried it was disrespectiful of me. No, no displeasure was expressed.

Comment: So you're worried you were disrespectful by sending via email instead of in person?

Comment: You're making an assumption that's making you feel bad but really there's nothing to be done so stop worrying.

Answer (score 9):

What are you hoping to accomplish by talking to her ? I am pretty sure she understood your apology through email already, and she had no problem with your action since she answered it by *nice comments and her willingness to provide recommendations if I ever need one.*

If you need to talk to her about some subject, you can just talk to her as you normally would. On your resignation, this is already acted, and well accepted, and you should probably move on. Wasting her time for a non-problem would not help.

I do not think the situation is *bad*, so there is no *worsening* here.

Comment: agreed, let it be.  There's nothing bad, but apologizing may create something.  Silence is golden

Answer (score 2):

I would not consider the E-mail out of line or disrespectful, especially in a situation where schedule conflicts occur.  You did nothing wrong there in my opinion, so be a ease.  That said, before you leave, and generally at your next chance, I would recommend talking face to face.  Not really an apology, but a professional "Thank you and sorry".  It can be two minutes in passing, or a more formal exit interview type meeting as you, or you and she together think is appropriate.  The two minute in passing is an attempt to professionally make sure you remain on good terms, not burnt bridges, not leaving in a huff, just business, career or life choice.  The exit interview range is more formal, go over your job performance, how you felt about the job, maybe even if the company may be a part of your future plans, etc.  That might not be appropriate, it depends on the situation, but at least the quick face to face before exit usually is.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing unprofessional about an e-mail resignation.  While this is obviously someone you respect, in a **professional** sense, you don't owe her or anyone else any explanation.  If you got fired or laid off by the organization, she couldn't change that, nor vice versa.  You have met a *professional courtesy* (there's no legal requirement, in most situations in the US) to supply a written resignation and there's no need to be apologetic about taking care of *business*.